# What is Mobsync.exe? Assuming I don't need it, can I disable it in Windows 7 without ill side effect?

Tags: windows-7, sync, process

I'm running Windows 7.  Occasionally when I resume my computer from standby, it seems to wait 20-30 seconds or so before giving me full control back.  In an attempt to diagnose why, I've been watching what's going on using the awesome [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

One of the processes I've noticed being started during that hiccup time is `Mobsync.exe`, described as "Microsoft Sync Center".  Sync?  Sync *what*?

So, what is `Mobsync.exe` used for, exactly? Assuming I don't need its functionality, can I disable it in Windows 7 without ill side effect?  If so, what's the best way to disable `Mobsync.exe`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just realized I had left this open question dangling.  FWIW, I ended up finding the best explanation at [How-To Geek - What is Mobsync.exe and Why Is It Running?](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8668/what-is-mobsync.exe-and-why-is-it-running/).  Quote:

> Mobsync.exe is a process that belongs to Microsoft Sync Center and the
>   Offline Files feature. It’s associated with a device like a Windows
>   Mobile phone with ActiveSync, a SQL Server installation, or if you
>   have Internet Explorer (a feature in IE 6 not in IE7 or above) set to
>   synchronize pages for viewing offline. The process is not a threat and
>   shouldn’t be deleted if you’re using the feature. If you go into
>   Control Panel, you can launch Sync Center and manage its settings.

In terms of turning it off, the article continues:

> **Disable mobsync.exe in Windows 7**
>
> - Click on the Start Menu and enter *offline files* into the search box and hit Enter.
>     [image]
> - In the Offline Files window click the *Disable offline files* button then click Ok.
>     [image]
>
> You’ll need to restart the computer for the new setting to take
>   effect. After a reboot, the Sync Center icon should be gone and
>   [mobsync.exe] not be running in Task Manger.

Answer (score 1):

It also syncs offline files during logon and logoff.. check the below link for more info..

https://www.technlg.net/windows/what-is-mobsyncexe/

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Services via Control Panel -> Administrator Tools.
2. Scroll down the page until you locate a service called Portable Device Enumerator Service, then double click on it.
3. Change the ‘Startup Type' to Manual.
4. Click on the Stop button, then click on OK.
5. If prompted by UAC, select Continue.

Comment: Thanks - I've tried this: I've actually set Startup Type to "Disabled", yet I still see Mobsync.exe started after logging in (then it goes away).  What else might be launching it?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Mobile Synchronization Manager

If you use Mobile devices synched on the pc, NO.